# Issue with outside faucet, can't figure out how to fix or replace it

Tags: plumbing, faucet, outdoorfaucet

More more is coming out of the holes than the actual faucet spout. Not sure what these holes are for but I can't figure out how to remove this and replace it.

Any help would be most appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a vacuum breaker to prevent outside water being suck back into your water pipes.  Brought to you from the same people who say drinking from a water/garden hose is bad for you.  It might have a set/hex screw to lock it onto the threads of the faucet, but loosen the screw and it should just unscrew for replacement.

Comment: I have had my own corrode itself to the hose bib.  Had to replace the entire hose bib.  If you can get your's off you are a lucky person.  Turn lefty-loosey.  Try heat...it didn't help mine, but maybe it will yours..

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you need a new vacuum breaker.

If it comes off easy with a pipe wrench or slip joint pliers, then you’re in luck. (Never hurts to have a second wrench counteracting your twist.) The however is that some of those have a breakaway screw that locks them on. You’ll have to drill beside that broken screw to loosen it up enough for removal.

Comment: Is not a second wrench almost required for plumbing?